# How to run a neural network in R and connect to an OPEN instance of Excel?

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have Excel-VBA code which runs in an Excel-instance. While running the VBA-code I would like to call R to send input to a neural network in R and read the outcome back into the instance of Excel.

For this purpose I am looking for an R-package to connect R with an OPEN instance of Excel.

I have investigated Readxl, WriteXLS, Xlsx and XLConnect although these packages seem to need a saved Excel-file to read and a closed Excel file to write back to.

Does someone know if there is an R-package to connect R with an OPEN instance of Excel?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not run the NN in excel?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the [`excel.link` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/) might do what you need. See the [Calling R from Excel vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/vignettes/CallingRFromExcel.html) that goes with the package.

Comment: Also, googling [call R from vba](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-ab&ei=yjtSW-HFM4Lw9AOGwJSoBw&q=call+R+from+vba&oq=call+R+from+vba&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l3j0j0i8i30k1l3j0i30k1.2544.2544.0.2980.1.1.0.0.0.0.108.108.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.107....0.ri2IGUl9pEI) turns up a bunch of potentially useful links.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks. Nice that it connects to a running Excel, although it seems it is mainly focussed on operations from R into Excel. I am looking for the other direction. I will do some further reading.